# R flip XY axis on a plot

Tags: r, plot, flip

This seems like a trivial `R` question, but I didn't find any convincing solution. I would like to flip my plot where the X axis become Y, and vice-versa. In boxplot there is an `horiz="T"` option, but not in `plot()`.

This is what I plot :

```
plot(rm, type="l", main="CpG - running window 100")

> str(rm)
 num [1:43631] 0.667 0.673 0.679 0.685 0.691 ...
```

[image: This is what I have]

And I would like to obtain this :

[image]

Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: What you want seems to be identical to what you have. The graph is only rotated by 90°. Normaly you would rotate the graph when inserting it into a text document using LaTeX or Open Office. If you want something else, please clarify and give some data to make your example reproducible. Is rm a ts object?

Comment: The second plot is indeed rotated by hand with my pdf viewer. The rm is simply a list of ~40000 values ranging from 0 to 0.6. Sorry if I haven't phrased my question properly. Indeed I am after rotating the plot by 90%, which (to me) correspond to flipping the XY axis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is because the plot doesn't explicitly have an index. Try the following:

```
set.seed(1)
a = rnorm(200) # like your `rm` -- bad name for an object, by the way
plot(a, type="l", main="rnorm(200)") # index automatically added
```

This is similar what you have. It is also equivalent to `plot(1:length(a), a, ...)` where `1:length(a)` is your `x` and `a` is your `y`.

[image]

Keeping the above in mind, we can flip your chart like this:

```
# index specified, and X-Y swapped
plot(a, 1:length(a), type="l", main="rnorm(200)")
```

[image]

Comment: if you would rather have the x-axis on top, you will need to suppress it with plot(a, 1:length(a), type="l", main="rnorm(200)", xlab="", xaxt="n") and then axis(3).

Comment: @Marcinthebox, thanks. I didn't add that because I assumed that the default is sufficient and the OP had the x-axis at the top only because they had simply posted a rotated version of their original plot. I normally don't like gridlines, but if they are also printing at the scale of the plot in the question, they may also want to add a few (in this case, vertical) lines to help guide the eye....